# SVG sprite: With object embedded SVG images have unwanted padding

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite

I created a [SVG](https://cdn.mediacru.sh/KG1yCCqs7p3k.svg) in this way with three blocks:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="116" height="69" viewBox="0 0 116 69">
    <style><![CDATA[ svg svg { display: none; } svg svg:target { display: inline; }]]></style>
    <svg width="116" height="25" viewBox="0 0 116 25" id="block1" y="0">
        <path fill="#fff" stroke="#FF51D4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0 0h116v25H0z"/>
        <path fill="#D5FF54" stroke="#FF51D4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0 0h116v25H0z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="block2" y="25">
        <path fill="#FF001A" d="M.5.5h19v19H.5z"/>
        <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M19 1v18H1V1h18m1-1H0v20h20V0z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg width="27" height="24" viewBox="0 0 27 24" id="block3" y="45">
        <path d="M.5.5h26v23H.5z"/>
        <path fill="#6BFF4E" d="M26 1v22H1V1h25m1-1H0v24h27V0z"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

And I want to display only "block2" in my web page and I do it in this way:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" style="border:1px solid blue;" data="https://cdn.mediacru.sh/KG1yCCqs7p3k.svg#block2"></object>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpwqhxjm/) and you will see that I can display only "block2" but you will also see that there is a blue border which shows me that the dimensions are as big as the full SVG image. I have different sizes of SVG images inside the SVG and I need to display the images ("block1", "block2" and "block3") without this unwanted padding / white space.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://cdn.mediacru.sh/KG1yCCqs7p3k.svg#block2"></object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
object {
    margin-top: -26px;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a solution if I would have only two or three images, but not for hundred of images, because I had to calculate for every image.

Comment: Hundreds!? You have my sympathies. That's the best method I know :(

Comment: So, no one will use SVG sprites if this is the way how to integrate into a web page…

Comment: I did it with a external SVG file with ``<svg style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"><use xlink:href="spritemap.svg#logo"></svg>`` and for IE there is a library: https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody